# Wordpress next/previous post button custom HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to show a field from ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) in the link to the next/previous post. 
And i can't figure out how to show this. For as for as i can find ACF field can only be displayed with PHP and i can't display PHP inside the code i have now.

Does anyone know how to show this without PHP or how to add PHP to my code?

I currently use this code

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<div id="vorigePostKnop"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>  <div id="venster">%title<br>%date  </div>  </div> ' ); ?>
```

English isn't my first language. I hope you can understand.

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired output is?

Comment: A text field in which i have an IMG tag with flickr as source. <?php the_field('uitgelichteAfbeelding'); ?> is normal PHP with as output <img src="http://placehold.it/400x250"/>

Comment: Where should that image go in the post link? Are you looking for something like this: `<div id="vorigePostKnop"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>  <div id="venster">%title<br>%date <img src="placehold.it/400x250"/></div>  </div>`. Can you updated the question with the full desired output of `previous_post_link`

Comment: Something exactly like that would be perfect.

Comment: All i basicly need to find out is how to output the AFC field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `get_field` function to get the field as a string, as opposed to outputting it with `the_field`:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Then just concatenate it into your link:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<div id="vorigePostKnop"><i class="fa fa-play"></i>  <div id="venster">%title<br>%date ' . get_field('uitgelichteAfbeelding') . '</div>  </div> ' ); ?>
```